# Error callback in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a Jquery method to trigger an Ajax call.

```
function fetchQuestion(questionId,index){

    $.ajax({
        url: '${createLink(action: 'fetchQuestion')}',
        data: {id:questionId,grantAssessmentId:${grantAssessmentId}},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('div[id="questionContent"]').html(html);
        },
        error: function(e,status){
            console.log("inside error..")
        }
    });
}
```

In the Controller's action, I throw an exception(throw new Exception("Some Message")) that returns 500 response for the ajax call. But in the error callback I am not able to catch it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean. The `error` handler should execute when the response is anything other than `200 OK`, so you should see the `inside error...` in the console.

Comment: But I am not able to see it.

Comment: Have you checked the console to ensure that the response is being sent at all?

Comment: Actually the issue was related to the incorrect method execution. It works now. Thanks Rory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the third argument, you will get thrown error there

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, **String errorThrown** )

Comment: It should not make any difference.

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: please screenshot post the screenshot of response in console.